# requests.user returns AnonymousUser when used in api view other than login

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

## I am using Django's default authentication and authorization system. I have used DRF in backend and React in frontend

```
#views.py

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login
from .models import *
from .serializers import *
import json
# Create your views here.

@api_view(['GET'])
def slips(requests):
    if requests.method == 'GET':
        data = slip.objects.all()
        serializer = slipserializer(data,many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def packages(requests):
    if requests.method == 'GET':
        data = package.objects.all()
        serializer = packageserializer(data,many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
@api_view(['POST'])
def register(requests):
    if requests.method == 'POST':
        try:
            data = requests.body.decode('utf-8')
            ref_data = json.loads(data)
            usr = User.objects.create_user(ref_data['firstname'],ref_data['email'],ref_data['password'])
            usr.last_name = ref_data['lastname']
            usr.save()
            login(requests,usr)
            return Response({'message':'registered successfully'})
        except:
            return Response({'message':'something went wrong'})

@api_view(['POST'])
def logIn(requests):
    if requests.method == 'POST':
        try:
            data = requests.body.decode('utf-8')
            ref_data = json.loads(data)
            uname = User.objects.get(email = ref_data['ID'])
            usr = authenticate(username = uname,password = ref_data['password'])
            login(requests,usr)
            return Response({'message': 'successfully logged in'})
        except:
            print('failed')
            return Response({'message': 'something went wrong'})
        

@api_view(['GET'])
def projects(requests):
    if requests.method == 'GET':
        proj = project.objects.all()
        serializer = projectserializer(proj,many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def skills(requests):
    if requests.method == 'GET':
        sk = skill.objects.all()      
        serializer = skillserializer(sk,many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
@api_view(['GET'])
def tech(requests):
    if requests.method == 'GET':
        tech = technology.objects.all()
        serializer = technologyserializer(tech,many = True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def placeorder(requests):
    if requests.method == 'POST':
        #returns anonymous user here
        usr = requests.user
        print(usr)
        data = requests.body.decode('utf-8')
        ref_data = json.loads(data)
        pack = package.objects.get(id = ref_data['product_id'])
        order.objects.create(pack = pack,timeframe = ref_data['time'],goals = ref_data['goals'],questions = ref_data['questions'],audience = ref_data['audience'],status = 'initiated')
        return Response('package oredered succesfully')
```

```
//using axios to send data
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/placeorder/',
            data: {
                'product_id': Id,
                'goals': goals,
                'time': time,
                'questions': questions,
                'audience': audience
            },
            headers: {
                'X-CSRFToken': 'CSRF_TOKEN',
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
```

I want user to buy some packages for that I should put the username in every order object so that I come to know which user has bought which package and when I tried to know who is the current user in order view using `requests.user` it returns `AnonymousUser` even when user is logged In and if I do same thing inside login view it returns current user

Comment: i always struggle to identify where the problem lays exactly with the mixed framework questions...  which part is failing ?